# Remove time periods from daily data

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset of hourly observations with the format `%Y%m%d %H:%M` that results like this `2020-03-01 01:00:00` for various days. How can filter filter out a certain time interval? My goal is to maintain the observations between 08:00 and 20:00.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the hour value from the column and keep the rows between 8 and 20 hours.

```
df$hour <- as.integer(format(df$datetime, '%H'))
result <- subset(df, hour >= 8 & hour <= 20)
result

#               datetime hour
#9   2020-01-01 08:00:00    8
#10  2020-01-01 09:00:00    9
#11  2020-01-01 10:00:00   10
#12  2020-01-01 11:00:00   11
#13  2020-01-01 12:00:00   12
#14  2020-01-01 13:00:00   13
#15  2020-01-01 14:00:00   14
#16  2020-01-01 15:00:00   15
#17  2020-01-01 16:00:00   16
#18  2020-01-01 17:00:00   17
#19  2020-01-01 18:00:00   18
#20  2020-01-01 19:00:00   19
#21  2020-01-01 20:00:00   20
#33  2020-01-02 08:00:00    8
#34  2020-01-02 09:00:00    9
#35  2020-01-02 10:00:00   10
#...
#...
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'UTC'), 
                      as.POSIXct('2020-01-10 00:00:00', tz = 'UTC'), 'hour'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
between(hour( your_date_value ), 8, 19)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.